# Will adding large columns (VARCAHR) to MySQL table have significant impact on performance?

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications

I am sorry if the question is somewhat newbish, I have little knowledge of databases.

I am working on a web based application to manage the organization users. The number of records will be 10,000-20,000. I wanted to add another column to the table to allow the staff to add notes to the users record, just in case. I assume this will not be utilized very often.

Will adding VARCHAR column to the table have a significant performance impact on the DB? Would you suggest separating the notes to another table, relational to the users table?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a large `varchar()` column *can* have an impact on performance, but not necessarily.  The key idea here is storing data on pages in the database.  Reading a table requires reading all the pages that contain records.  Normally, many records fit on a single page.  If a record is quite large, then only a few records fit on a page.  This can affect performance because more pages need to be read (for certain queries) or the records don't all fit into memory.

In any case, there are mitigating circumstances:

- You can have the field and never populate it.  Hence, the record sizes are never very large.
- All your queries are "needle-in-the-haystack" queries, where you are using an index to fetch only one or a few records.
- If you actually store the column as `text`, then it is a separately allocated object.
- If you only have a "few" users, so the total data size is small (say measured in a few megabytes), then performance probably isn't an issue.

There are also methods to mitigate performance, such as putting the longer columns in a separate table.

So, the impact on performance depends on the overall size of the database, its structure, and how it will be used.